# Efficient Algorithm to find max result from adding given number to the summation of all elements or its complement in a list

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, math

Suppose I have  number  `x`, list of numbers   and max number `y`.  I  need to find maximum result I can obtain from adding `x` to either addition or subtraction of each element in the list such that the summation does not exceed `y` and does not go below 0.

Note: you must either add or subtract each element in the list which means you cannot skip numbers.

**Example:**

```
x= 3 y=10  list={2,6,1}
```

Max i can get : `3 - 2 + 6 +1 = 8`   which is less than 10 and >0

**failure case** for this will be `3+2+6+1= 12`   which is > y  so is invalid solution.

**Another failure case**   `3-2-6    = -5`    (no need here to check elements after 6 ,since you got -ve number which is refused)

How can I find this maximal value?

Comment: Seeing your "slow" implementation would've been nice.

Comment: SO is not a `Post your homework, get your code` site.

Comment: I would backtrack it, and put all of the possible answers into an object in an ArrayList. The object would contain both the solution, and the equation that got to the solution. Then sort the ArrayList by solution, and pick the value(s) closest to y without going over.

Comment: This is not homework sir,this is sub-problem i am facing in part of project doing it for my own use !

Comment: SO is not a `Post your project requirements, get your code` site.

Comment: @Servy: I disagree - questions such as "how to approach this problem" is OK for SO, "we" don't only "accept" questions such as: "How to split a string in java" or "I have a bug in my code, can you find it". Algorithmic questions are perfectly fine as well, why won't they be?

Comment: Downvoters: Really - what's wrong with the question? It is a perfectly valid question, the OP is not asking for a complete code, he asks for an algorithm (`even pseudo`), and the problem is not trivial, in fact - [there is a 1,000,000$ on who can solve it polynomially - or prove it cannot be done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem).

Comment: @amit He is asking for the complete code, he's just saying that he'll accept a partial solution if that's all he can get.  Clearly getting the algorithm, without the code, is not his preference though.  He also put virtually no effort into asking the question, hence the downvotes.  He pretty much just copy/pasted his requirements and asked for a solution.  He demonstrated no effort in attempting to solve the problem, in attempting to find other existing solutions to the problem, etc.  He just asked for us to do everything he needs to do for him.  Such laziness is often met with downvotes.

Comment: no i am not asking for complete code,i was thinking in algorithms on paper and in my mind ,so there is no code to write here because i was not able to find algorithm to write code + this question is not copied from somewhere else and i am the one who came up with this example by the way,because when i divided my project into parts and came up to solve this part i was not able to do so i asked here for help !  @amit thank you for the edit ,question is better now

Answer (score 3):

So, you basically have a list `l`, and a number `y-x` (if you must add `x`, and get `y`, it is easy to see it is equivalent to get `y-x`) and you want to add/subtract each element in `l` and get closest as possible to the value `y-x`.

Note that the problem is equivalent to the [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), since if you have a list `l`, and values such that `y-x == 0` - you need to find two sublists `l1,l2` such that `sum(l1) - sum(l2) == 0`, and `l1 union l2 = l` which is exactly the partition problem.

Thus - there is no known polynomial solution to the problem.

I'd have a look at exponential (backtracking for example) solution, or a variation on the [pseudo polynomial DP solution for the related subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution).

Comment: Thank you :) i will read the Partition problem and the DP solution and give you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
    int x = 3, y = 10;
    var lst = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int n = (int)Math.Pow(2, lst.Count);
    var lst2 = new List<List<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var lstCopy = new int[lst.Count];
        lst.CopyTo(lstCopy);
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j *= 2)
            if ((j & i) != 0)
                lstCopy[(int)Math.Log(j, 2)] *= -1;
        lst2.Add(lstCopy.ToList());
    }
    bool yes = lst2.Select(l=>x + l.Sum()).Any(l=>l > 0 && l < y);
    if (yes)
        Console.WriteLine(lst2.Select(l => x + l.Sum()).Where(l => l > 0 && l < y).First());
```

Note here that you will need to check 2^n arrays of integers where n is the length of your original array(it's your {2, 6, 1})